# How to validate data in dynamically created table rows that are input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a dynamically created table where row2 and column2 onward elements are input fields. User can change these fields and submit.

I want to put a check so that in any row:

- The 1st input field should not be greater than 2nd, 3rd or 4th
- The 2nd input field should not be greater than 3rd or 4th. And it should not be smaller than 1st.
- The 3rd input field should not be greater than 4th. And it should not be smaller than 1st or 2nd.
- The 4th input field should not be smaller than 1st or 2nd or 3rd.

So if the user tries to change any value to an invalid value and click submit button, then an error message should be displayed and form should not be submitted. So only option on the message window should be an OK button which should bring the user back to the old page (before changes were made to any field).

I tried doing it by making use of getElementById() and giving same id for all four input fields in a row, but the getElementById() returns the first element if more than one id exists (id not being unique).

I checked possibility to try getElementsByName() but the value of name attribute  is being generated dynamically and only "_good_high", "_warning_low", "_warning_high" and "_critical_low" is constant part of it.

Can you please suggest me some way to add this validation?

Link to jsfiddle is [ExampleFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddle300/e75evmxo/2/)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CommDesk AdminPage</title>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
addPlusSign();
$(".btn1").click(function(){
$(".expand1").toggle();
var btn1Text = $(".btn1").text();
if(btn1Text.indexOf("+") > -1){
var temp = btn1Text.replace(/\+|\-/ig, '-');
$(".btn1").text(temp);
} else if (btn1Text.indexOf("-") > -1){
var temp = btn1Text.replace(/\+|\-/ig, '+');
$(".btn1").text(temp);
}
});
})
function addPlusSign(){
if($(".expand1")){
var btn1Text = $(".btn1").text();
$(".btn1").text(btn1Text + " [+]");
}
}
$(function () {
$('.admin-form')
//we need to save values from all inputs with class 'admin-input'
.find(':input.admin-input')
.each(function () {
//save old value in each input's data cache
$(this).data('oldValue', $(this).val())
})
.end()
.submit(function (ev) {
var changed = false;
$(':input.admin-input', this).filter(function () {
if($(this).val() != $(this).data('oldValue')){
changed = true;
}
});
if($(this).hasClass('changed') && (!changed)){
alert("None of the thresholds were changed!");
ev.preventDefault()
}
if($(this).hasClass('changed') && changed){
var allowSubmit = window.confirm("You have set a unique threshold for one or more sub-elements below. Are you sure you want to reset them all?")
if (!allowSubmit)
ev.preventDefault()
}
});
});
$(document).on('input', '.admin-input', function(){
$(this).closest('form').addClass('changed');
});
</script>

<style>
.expand1 { display: none;
}
.btn1 { cursor: pointer;
}
body {
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
font: 15px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
span.note1 {float:left}
span.note2 {font-size:90%}
table#t02, #t02 th, #t02 td {
border: none;
border-collapse: collapse;
font-size:90%;
font-weight:normal;
}

#button1{
position: relative;
top:10px;
left:75%;
color: white;
background-color: rgb(0,89,132);
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" method="post" class="admin-form">
<div style="float:left; width:50%">
<table id="t02" class="table2">
<tr>
<th style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"></th>
<th></th>
<th style="padding:0 10px 0 0;">Green</th>
<th colspan="3" style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Yellow</th>
<th></th>
<th style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Red</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="btn1" style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"><b>Row1</b></td>
<td>&lt</td>
<td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="text", class="admin-input", name="acd_call_volume_good_high", value="50", id="1", size="3", maxlength="3"></td>
<td><input type="text", class="admin-input", name="acd_call_volume_warning_low", value="50", id="1", size="3", maxlength="3"></td>
<td>to</td>
<td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="text", class="admin-input", name="acd_call_volume_warning_high", value="100", id="1", size="3", maxlength="3"></td>
<td>&gt</td>
<td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="text", class="admin-input", name="acd_call_volume_critical_low", value="100", id="1", size="3", maxlength="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" class="expand1">SubRow1</td>
<td class="expand1">&lt</td>
<td class="expand1"><input type="text", name="acd_call_volume_good_high_SubRow1", value="50", id="2", size="3", maxlength="3"></td>
<td class="expand1"><input type="text", name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_SubRow1", value="50", id="2", size="3", maxlength="3"></td>
<td class="expand1">to</td>
<td class="expand1"><input type="text", name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_SubRow1", value="100", id="2", size="3", maxlength="3"></td>
<td class="expand1">&gt</td>
<td class="expand1"><input type="text", name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_SubRow1", value="100", id="2", size="3", maxlength="3"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" id="button1" style="height:50px; width:100px"/>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From your example I don't see any dynamic generation of tables.

Comment: Hi Griffin, actually this example is the smallest subset of the html page which is generated by a perl script. I just reduced it to smallest size possible. I think I should have mentioned this in the post. The entire webpage that is generated has 11-12 collapsible rows in this table and there are 2 more tables with different data. All these tables show the data fetched from the MySQL table and when the form is submitted by clicking submit button, the changed values are updated in the same MySQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following snippet to you main `$(function() {....`

```
$( '.admin-input' ).change( function( e ) {
    temp = e.target.name.split( '_' )
    col = temp[ temp.length-2 ] + '_' + temp[ temp.length-1 ]
    #validation logic
})
```

`col` will give you the last part of the changed cell's name e.g. `warning_low`. From there you can do any validation you want.

If you can change your perl code to change the names of the cells slightly so there is a better delimiter to split on, it would clean the code up a little ( e.g. `acd_call_volume-warning_low` ) but it's not so important.

I would also google for "jquery validator"

Comment: Hi Griffin. Thanks for the suggestion. Definitely I am going to give it try and check for "jquery validator" as well. But the class "admin.input" is assigned only for rows that are main rows (like Row1) and not for sub rows (like SubRow1. Hidden rows that will be visible when main row is expanded by clicking on the + sign.). The problem here is that validation logic I want to add is needed for both main rows and sub rows. If I use class "admin.input" then I think validation will be applied only on main rows and not sub rows. Please let me know if I got it right or have missed something.

Comment: @300 You need to target those fields. Either do it by changing the selector in the jQuery to something more complex or change your perl code to output HTML which makes it easier for you to target those fields.